# Pass a object params by onPress() in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I try to pass a object parameter by onPress() in PlanScreen to PlanDetailScreen, but error occurred as 'TypeError; undefined is not an object(evaluating 'detail.weekNumber').
How to solve it?

```js
function PlanDetailScreen({ detail }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text key={detail.weekNumber}>{"Week " + detail.weekNumber}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

function PlanScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <FlatList
      numColumns={5}
      data={PlanData}
      renderItem={({ detail }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={(detail) =>
            navigation.navigate("PlanDetailScreen", { detail })
          }
        >
          <Text key={detail.weekNumber}>{"Uke\n" + detail.weekNumber}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What [Muhammad said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62461395/8437254) is right, but you also have to take into account that navigation params come in the `route` prop of the screen.

It would look something like this:

```
function PlanDetailScreen({ route }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text key={detail.weekNumber}>{"Week " + route.params.detail.weekNumber}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

function PlanScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <FlatList
      numColumns={5}
      data={PlanData}
      renderItem={({ detail }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate("PlanDetailScreen", { detail })
          }
        >
          <Text key={detail.weekNumber}>{"Uke\n" + detail.weekNumber}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Take a look at:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `detail`  that is why detail is undefined just remove it from `onPress`

```
function PlanDetailScreen({ detail }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text key={detail.weekNumber}>{"Week " + detail.weekNumber}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

function PlanScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <FlatList
      numColumns={5}
      data={PlanData}
      renderItem={({ detail }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate("PlanDetailScreen", { detail })
          }
        >
          <Text key={detail.weekNumber}>{"Uke\n" + detail.weekNumber}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```